# How to Show JSF error message in between text fields when error occurs

Tags: css, jsf

I have a panel layout which has some text fields that require validation. What I need is to let error messages be shown between the fields (not on top or behind them): i.e I want the error message to take its own space and/or drag down the other text fields when the error occurs and everything returns to the way it was when the error vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean to use multiple

```
<h:message for="..." ... />
```

instead of single

```
<h:messages ... />
```

?

Comment: No, I am using multiple  <ice:message  but the problem is that the messages come above the panel (covers other text fields...etc).

Comment: I guess the problem is in your html markup (or IceFaces' rendered markup). Can you update your post and show the markup and screenshot?